# TornadoFX: How to preserve `ItemViewModel`'s property?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Good day.
I am trying to preserve a property of [`ItemViewModel`](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/11.%20Editing%20Models%20and%20Validation.html) via [`config`](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Config%20Settings%20and%20State.html) helper. I am able to successfully save the property (`conf` directory with appropriate `.properties` file is generated), however upon next start, the property does not restore its value, just remains `null`. Here's a sample code to demonstrate my issue:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import tornadofx.*

data class Foo(val doNotPreserveMe: String, val preserveMe: String)

class FooModel : ItemViewModel<Foo>() {
    val doNotPreserveMe = bind { item?.doNotPreserveMe?.toProperty() }
    val preserveMe = bind { SimpleStringProperty(item?.preserveMe, "pm", config.string("pm")) }
}

class FooApp : App(FooView::class)

class FooView : View() {
    private val model = FooModel()

    override val root = form {
        fieldset {
            field("Do not preserve me") { textfield(model.doNotPreserveMe).required() }
            field("Preserve me") { textfield(model.preserveMe).required() }
            button("Do something") {
                enableWhen(model.valid)
                action {
                    model.commit {
                        // ...
                        with(config) {
                            set("pm" to model.preserveMe.value)
                            save()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why the model is not restoring the value?

Comment: Can you post a complete sample app? I suspect you're accessing different `config` objects when reading and writing.

Comment: @EdvinSyse, I've edited my OP to include a sample code that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Component has it's own `config` store, which is backed by a separate file. Either make sure to use the same config file, or the app global config file.

You can refer to other component's `config` store, so one solution would be to let the View access the ViewModel's config store like this:

```
button("Do something") {
    enableWhen(model.valid)
    action {
        model.commit {
            // ...
            with(model.config) {
                set("pm" to model.preserveMe.value)
                save()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a much simpler and more contained solution, which is simply to handle save in the FooModel's `onCommit` callback

```
override fun onCommit() {
    with(config) {
        set("pm" to preserveMe.value)
        save()
    }
}
```

In this case you'd simply call `model.commit()` in the button callback.

You can also use a common, or even global config object. Either use a Controller's config store, or the global store. To use the global config object, just refer to `app.config` in both the model and the view.

Comment: The `onCommit()` member function is a splendid solution. IMHO, this pattern (validation + config) is worth mentioning in tornadoFX guide.

Comment: Great! A small PR against the guide would be much appreciated, I'm a little pressed for time these days myself you see :)